# Canvas mouse click, offsets and parent nodes

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I am new to canvas and I need to know the coordinates where the mouse was clicked. I was successful with:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('MainMap');

canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', onMapMouseDown, false);
```

The problem comes when I try to get the right coordinates. I tried

```
var x = ev.x - canvas.offsetLeft;

var y = ev.y - canvas.offsetTop;
```

except that canvas.offsetLeft = 0 and canvas.offsetTop = 40. (Actually it is right since the canvas is placed at that position in a div).
The div is in another div that is in a table that is in a div..... and so on.

The Solution to get the right position would be by adding offsets in a recursive function by getParentNode();
The question is then. How do I now I've reached the Top level node. May be the document or the top level div or table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to traverse every node. `offsetLeft` and `offsetTop` represent the distance of the element respect to its `offset parent`. And what is the `offsetParent`? Well, it's the first ancestor of a node that has a `position` different from `static` (this is, `relative`, `absolute` or `fixed`).

Fortunately for you, DOM elements contain a property named `offsetParent` which indicates what ancestor is the offset parent, so...

```
var offset = {x: 0, y: 0};
var node = canvas;
while (node) {
    offset.x += node.offsetLeft;
    offset.y += node.offsetTop;
    node = node.offsetParent;
}
```

This goes on until node is the document, which is placed at (0, 0).

Another, quicker way, is uing jQuery:

```
var offset = $('#MainMap').offset();
```

Comment: It worked out. I had to make some adjustment to make it work in firefox (It did not like "ev.x") but it seems to work in all brosers now. Thank you very much for helping a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to use the 'screen' width and height.. Script libraries like Kinetic.js make this a lot easier for you. Still, if you insist on writing the functionality yourself, I found this tutorial quite helpful:

http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-mouse-coordinates/

Or this blog post:

http://miloq.blogspot.be/2011/05/coordinates-mouse-click-canvas.html